# How did Spanish "Sevilla" become English "Seville"?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary, pronunciation, spanish

In Spanish, the name of this city is spelled *Sevilla* and pronounced /seˈβiʎa/, but in English it is spelled *Seville* and pronounced /sɛˈvɪl/.

Having never heard of Sevilla/Seville until I went to Spain for four months, I only ever heard the Spanish pronunciation. Personally, when I started hearing English speakers say "Seville" in the States and in England I couldn't help but wince and thought it was wrong (everybody I knew in Spain, both English- and Spanish-speaking, pronounced it the Spanish way). To me, it sounded like people pronouncing the the l's in *quesadilla.* But now people call me pretentious for saying it the Spanish way (yet it's not pretentious to say *quesadilla* properly...), and I've since come to learn *Seville* is standard English. How did these pronunciations come to be? Did the English one come about just through mispronunciation of the Spanish?

Comment: An unresearched guess would be that it came into English through Norman French at a stage before geminate /lː/ had become palatalised (in both French and Spanish). The modern French name is _Séville_ /seˈvij/ which, unless my French sound change chronology is mixed up, would still have been /seˈvilː(ə)/ up until a good while after the Norman Invasion into England. _Quesadilla_ and similar words were of course borrowed from modern-day Spanish, long after /lː/ had become /ʎ/.

Comment: Mispronunciation? Perhaps all those Spanish people are just mistaken.

Comment: @Janus - that sounds like a good 'unresearched' answer!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Your sound-change history sounds right, but it doesn’t matter in this case. The OED has *Seville* as entering English in the LME of the 1400s, so long after the Conquest though before the Discovery. The oldest citation is: “1436 *Libel Eng. Policy* 54 in *Pol. Poems* (Rolls) II. 160 ― Lycorys, Syvyle [*marg. note* Cyvylle] oyle, and grayne.”  After that it was variously spelled things like *Sivil, Sevil, Cevil*, with the *Seville* spelling not settling down until the 18th century. (I note that Lady Dorothy Savile was born in 1699.)

Comment: @tchrist Strictly speaking, that entry is Seville **oil**, which may be earlier than the common name for the city, or may be later (probably more likely). And actually, I’m thinking modern French _Séville_ must be either a re-borrowing or an adaptation to the modern Spanish pronunciation because, as John says in his comment to William’s answer, place names in _-ville_ usually have /l/, not /j/ in French.

Comment: @Damon So is saying "Spain" too low class for you as well? Should we be pronouncing "España" instead?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I wonder whether this question doesn’t come down to the same as asking why we don’t pronounce the cities whose real names are  [paʁi], [ˈmʏnçn̩],  [mɐˈskva],  [kʰøb̥m̩ˈhɑʊ̯ˀn], [liʒˈboɐ], and  [maˈðɾiθ] that way — not to mention [ˈkaðiθ],  [θaɾaˈɣoθa],  [baʎaðoˈlið], and [xiˈχõⁿ].

Comment: @tchrist To some degree, yes; but most of those easier to disentangle. Some of them are clearly just written names being pronounced as though they were English words (Paris, Madrid, Cadiz, Zaragoza, Valladolid, Gijon—except when the latter three are basically pronounced as approximations of the Spanish), and others are English exonyms whose origins are easier to find (Copenhagen, Lisbon); but how exactly the English names of Moscow and Munich came about would be equally good questions, I think.

Comment: Imagine my surprise when my 75-yr. old German aunt visiting the US for the first time, finally asked me (in German because she spoke absolutely no English) what "Germany" meant and why did we keep saying it and looking at her? lol!

Comment: @William No need to be rude William. I'm asking this question of out of ignorance. Not to mention you would never describe me as "high class" if you met me. I'm sitting here with no shirt on holding a beer in my falling apart living room...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seville is just the French spelling. That's where we got the word from. And in general, we pronounce foreign words in English in accordance with English norms and not how they were pronounced in their original language. There's nothing wrong with that.

Where I'm from, there are many Spanish names (i.e "Amarillo Texas", "Los Angeles"), and they are pronounced phonetically as they would be in English and not how they are in Spanish.

Comment: That does not address the pronunciation.

Comment: It does if we assume it was borrowed via French, which is likely. French final _-ville_ retains the /l/, so it would be present in an English borrowing.

Comment: @John Except _Séville_ in French doesn’t: it’s pronounced [seˈvij].

Comment: But that's modern French; when did the /l/ drop?

Comment: @JohnLawler That's the question. In most place names, it didn't (_Albertville_, for instance, has an /l/). My guess would be that the name was first taken as a Spanish name and adapted to French (i.e., feminine marker _-a_ replaced with _-e_) early on, and then fairly recently, the pronunciation was changed to better fit the modern Spanish one. I have no idea when that happened, though.

Comment: I don't understand. In French, it's ville and the Spanish is villa. Two different pronunciations. Frenchifying it does not mean the Spanish [ʎ] [as in calle and Sevilla] is kept.

Comment: @Lambie: French: *ville* /vil/; *fille* /fij/; *Séville*: /sevij/. The name *Séville* is not pronounced as *Sé* with *ville* on the end.

Comment: @Peter Shor Yes, la ville et Séville are not pronounced the same way. But the French follows French logic: la Colombie (French), Colombia (Spanish), where a Spanish ***a*** becomes an ***e*** in French. French does not have a final letter a or o. The tonic stress in French is always on the last syllable but tends to get rid of Spanish or Portuguese a's and o's. For example, the state of Pernambuco in French is said: Pernambuc unless there's a dipthong: Bahia.

Comment: @Lambie: But the question is: why is there an /l/ in ***English***, when neither French nor Spanish has an /l/. Not where the French pronunciation came from.

Comment: @Peter Shor Because it came into English through the spelling, not via the pronunciation. Another example that is similar to this is cul de sac. In English, we take that and make  it cull de sac. People see words in writing and then apply their own pronunciation logic to them. The Spanish name Ruiz where it's i: becomes Ruez e, because in English for you to get i:, you usually need a final letter e: wheeze or a double ee as in sheep. The sound system usually trumps (god that word is now spoiled) the writing system.